# How add empty namespace to simpleXML element

Tags: php, simplexml, xml-namespaces

In order to simulate XML retrieved from a SOAP web service in a local php test environment version of the web service, I wish to add an empty namespace to an element, just as supplied by the actual web service itself.

But when I add a null string namespace argument to the addChild method, it is not added. Any other value does give me a namespace, but as I said I wish to have an empty one.

So

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<cdhead/>');
$nako = $xml -> addChild ('nako', '000', '');
```

gives me

```
<cdhead>
    <nako>000</nako>
</cdhead>
```

But I wish to have

```
<cdhead>
    <nako xmlns="">000</nako>
</cdhead>
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why do you want an empty namespace in the middle of the document? this sounds strange to me

Comment: @hek2mgl Because my supplier does the same and I wish to mimic that in my test environment.

Comment: What is your php version? I tried your example and it gaves me what you expected.

Comment: @hek2mgl As I said, then I get<cdhead>
<nako xmlns="name.spa.ce/test/">0000</nako>
</cdhead>. And when I use ' ' as namespace, I get <cdhead>
<nako xmlns=" ">0000</nako></cdhead>. The only one that does not work is the null string :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is because you are using php 5.2. Its a bug and was fixed in the PHP 5.2 series. Here you can view the [Bugreport](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41947). I've tested using PHP 5.3 and your example works out of the box. This should work in any case:

```
<?php

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<cdhead/>');
$nako = $xml -> addChild ('nako', '000');
$nako->addAttribute('xmlns', '');

echo $nako->saveXml();
```

It adds the attribute manually if the PHP version is lower than 5.3

**UPDATE** I tried this with PHP 5.2.17-dotdeb too and it worked out of the box, both

- addAttribute
- addChild with empty string as namespace

Comment: Nice try but that does not work well: when I add that statement then the nako element is not present any more. Also when I add just a plain addAttribute then the same occurs. And I realize now that I shd have mentioned that I tried addAttribute xmlns already - with no effect.

Comment: Hard to say. I've tested my example using PHP 5.3 (without the if ( PHP_VERSION ) of course) $nako->addAttribute('xmlns', '') worked

Comment: It transpires that it's my application that cuts off the empty namespaces. When I open the php in a browser and view the source, then I see the xml plus empty NS. Actually with above code it gives the xmlns value twice, which apparently is rejected by my application as invalid.

Comment: I've already fixed this. Hard work for a 'When I opened in browser I can see it' .... :|